# Intersection of two moving line segments (or a moving line segment and a point)

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

I'm trying to design a 2D physics engine with continuous collision detection.  Objects are stored as a list of non-rotating line-segments.  Therefore I can detect collisions by finding the collision time between each pair of line segments between any two objects.

I want to find the **exact** time for an intersection between two moving line-segments that are moving in a constant direction, and it is proving to be difficult.

I have figured out that I can simplify the problem further by finding the collision time between each point on a line-segment and the other line-segment (and vice versa).  It's possible that it is computationally inefficient, so a general solution for two line segments would be the ideal answer.  I can also ignore the case in which lines are parallel (I want to treat a line/point sharing the same position and velocity as 'no collision').

If the answer is "not possible" to **exactly** find this intersection time, I would accept it as a solution.  Any help on the subject would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: According to Wikipedia's article on a [Line segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment), for a line segment with endpoints `A = (a_x, a_y)` and `C = (c_x, c_y)`, a general equation for the line segment looks like this:

[image: Wikipedia's article on line segment - a general equation]

For a line-segment--point intersection, would substituting

- `p_x + p_v * t` for `a_x` (left-side only, right-side is just `p_x`)
- `p_y + p_v * t` for `a_y` (left-side only, right-side is just `p_y`)
- `q_x + q_v * t` for `c_x` (left-side only, right-side is just `q_x`)
- `q_y + q_v * t` for `c_y` (left-side only, right-side is just `q_y`)
- `r_x + r_v * t` for `x`
- `r_y + r_v * t` for `y`

for a line segment pq `[(p_x, p_y), (q_x, q_y)]`, point r `(r_x, r_y)`, moving at rates of `p_v` == `q_v` != `r_v` be solvable for t?  Here's the full equation:

[image: Full equation for line-segment--point intersection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation I have up above is incorrect in that it uses the same velocity for both its x and y components.

Since velocity is constant, I can simplify the equation such that the point is moving in reference to the line segment.  The amount of variables used for velocity reduces greatly, by using `v = r_v - qp_v` for the velocity of the point `r`, and `0` for the velocity of each line segment.  The equation with the variables plugged in then becomes:

[image: Equation for a point moving in reference to a line-segment]

Thanks to WolframAlpha, the equation is then solved for t:

[image: Equation solved for time t]

What's interesting is that if you analyze this, it's symmetrical for 3D.  Cross product for `[x1, y1, 0]` and `[x2, y2, 0]` is  `[0, 0, x1*y2 - y1*x2]`.  This equation then translates into:

[image: 3D translation]

Answer (score 0):

For a line-segment--point intersection, I can find an interval in which there is a collision (although this interval is larger than the actual time for the collision):

Given a line segment `[p, q]` moving at velocity `v`, and a point `r` with velocity `w`, `direction(w) != direction(v)`, define three lines `L1 = [p, p+v], L2 = [q, q+v], L3 = [r, r+w]`.  Let `t1, t_p` and `t2, t_q` be the intersection times between `L1` and `L3` and between `L2` and `L3`, respectively.  If the interval `[t1, t2]` is not mutually exclusive with `[t_p, t_q]`, then there is an intersection in the intersection of these two intervals (e.g. intersection between `[-1, 10]` and `[2, 20]` is `[2, 10]`).  If these intervals are mutually exclusive, then there is no collision.

Additionally, if the direction of `v` and `w` ARE the same, but not of equal length, then you can find the exact time of collision.  Let `s` be the point `r` when projected onto the line `[p, q]`.  If this point is in the line segment `[p, q]`, there is a collision at time `t1`, which can be calculated by dividing the distance between point `r` and point `s` by the relative velocity between the point `r` and the line-segment `[p, q]`.

Using the interval it's possible to get an estimate for the time by using a binary-search--like method of comparing distances between the segment and point at specific times.  This is very inefficient, however.